# Find files with certain strings in names (from a large list)

Tags: bash, shell, find, cygwin

I'm pretty new to scripting, and I'm using Cygwin to try and find file names that contain strings from a large list. I need to get an output list of the filenames or just move them all to a central directory (either is fine). It has to be able to check several directory levels (probably maxdepth 3). I've been doing this:

```
find ./incoming -type d \( -name "*012345*" -o -name "*678910*" -o -name "*111213*" \) > moved.txt
```

...except it's not ideal because the lists I'm working with can contain thousands of strings. I've also tried this:

```
xargs -a files_to_move.txt mv -t ./moved
```

...except since I don't know the whole names for the files, it's unsuccessful. Any ideas?

Comment: Something like: `find ./incoming -type f | grep -F -f files_to_move.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all strings are in `list.txt`

```
for i in $(cat list.txt); do find <your_dir> -name "*${i}*" ; done
```

Comment: It's taking a while, but I think this will work for me. Thanks!

Comment: Sean's solution is likely faster, as it will scan the directory only 1 time.